# Only One instance of this object can be true: Upon adding a new location, let all all other locations be set to false C#

Tags: c#

//Only one instance of this class can be current: upon creating a current location all other //locations(IsCurrent) should be set to false

```
public class CannisterLocation : BaseEntity
{
    public Guid CannisterId { get; set; }  
    public virtual Cannister Cannister { get; set; }
    public LocationDefinition LocationDefinition { get; set; }
    public bool IsCurrent { get; set; }

}
```

This is my cannister Class: The idea is that one cannister cannot be in two places at once but i can
see all the previous locations of my cannister with only one location being current

```
public class Cannister : BaseCannister
{
    
    public virtual ICollection<CannisterLocation> CannisterLocations { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: so what's the issue with your code?

Comment: Is that really the best design? Could not `Cannister` have a `CurrentLocation` that just returns the first/last item from it's `CannisterLocations` collection (depending on how you're building the collection). Storing that which can be computed just opens opportunities for errors.

Comment: in `Cannister` add `CurrentLocationId` make readonly prop `IsCurrent => LocationDefinition.Id == Cannister.CurrentLocationId` (I assume the Cannister is parent) .. when you set `CannisterLocation` current do `Canister.CurrentLocationId == LocationDefinition.Id `

Comment: Thank You everyone for your contribution. You guys Rock !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will depend on how you want to expand those classes, but here's another possibility:

```cs
       public class CannisterLocation : BaseEntity
       {
        public Guid CannisterId { get; set; }  
        public virtual Cannister Cannister { get; set; }
        public LocationDefinition LocationDefinition { get; set; }
        public bool IsCurrent { get; protected set; }
    
        static CannisterLocation  _current = null;
         public static CannisterLocation  Current 
         { 
             set
             {
                if (_current != null)
                    _current.IsCurrent = false;
    
                _current = value;
                _current.IsCurrent = true;
              }
              get
              {
                  return _current;
              }
          }
       }
```

Then you can implement somthing like

```cs
       public class Cannister : BaseCannister
       {
            
              public virtual ICollection<CannisterLocation> AllCannisterLocations { get; 
           /*protected*/ set; }
        
            public virtual AddNextLocation(CannisterLocation nextLoc)
            {     
              AllCannisterLocations.Add( nextLoc);
              CannisterLocation.Current = nextLoc;
            }
        
       }
```